# Problems with Watch Service API of nio2 class

Tags: java, filesystems, nio2

I am using Watch Service API of nio.2 class to watch a specific directory in my project(OS platform Ubuntu 11.10). whenever a change is made, for eg if a new file is added named abc.json to the watched directory it first fires the CREATED event and then immediately it fires a MODIFIED event. I came to know that this happens due to the fact that the OS first creates a 0 byte file and then modifies it. What changes should be made in the code given at http://java.dzone.com/news/how-watch-file-system-changes in order to get only CREATE event fired and not the MODIFIED event.

Secondly, when a MODIFY event is fired, event.context().toString(); method gives output something like this **.goutputstream-N2Z89V** instead of the filename as given by CREATED or DELETED event. How can me get the file name which is modified?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do some process on data then it's better to handle `Modify` event, because on creation time file has zero byte (empty file).

Try this to get file name

```
Path _directoryToWatch;
String path = _directoryToWatch.resolve(watchEvent.context()).toString();
```